# Do I need to worry about VSWR when antenna efficiency already includes return loss?

Tags: antenna, pcb-antenna

When I pick a WIFI chip antenna, the datasheet usually shows many parameters like VSWR and efficiency.  Given the efficiency already takes all the losses into account, why do I need to care about VSWR?

Comment: You care about VSWR because it tells you how much power is reflected back from the antenna to the transmitter. You will then understand why your transceiver released all of its magic blue smoke. Antenna efficiency **may** or **may not** take VSWR into account. Efficiency may only account for dielectric dissipation.

Comment: Thanks.  For ANT like http://www.ethertronics.com/files/1414/2386/9980/Embedded_LTE_1002289_20150213.pdf, does its efficiency include VSWR or not?

Comment: No, this is just radiation efficiency, which only accounts for the losses mentioned in Andy's answer (dielectric loss and skin depth effects). In addition the antenna you linked is placement sensitive, it's using the PCB as a ground plane so take the different radiation patterns / efficiency into account when you're designing your application board.

Answer (score 1):

VSWR tells you how close to 50 ohms your antenna looks like as a load at the end of a piece of coax. If VSWR is high then more power is reflected back to the transmitter to be consumed at the wrong end and less power is converted to a radio wave for radio transmission. An unfeasible VSWR of 50 reflects 92.3% of the power back towards the transmitter.

Antenna efficiency is the percentage of radiated power compared to non-reflected power. The losses are due to copper losses/skin loss and for more esoteric antennas (planar types) it's usually dielectric loss. Antenna efficiency doesn't cover reflected power due to VSWR.

So, if your VSWR is 50 meaning most power is reflected your antenna power efficiency may still be 90%.

Comment: Thanks Andy.  isn't ANT efficiency defined as the ratio of the radiated power to the input power?  So I assume reflected power should already been taken into account.   Thanks again.

Comment: I saw the efficiency definition from here: http://www.antenna-theory.com/basics/efficiency.php.  Thanks.

Comment: Reflected power due to impedance mismatch (aka bad VSWR) does not constitute input power.

Answer (score 0):

You care about VSWR because it tells you how much power is reflected back from the antenna to the transmitter. If this were for a high-power application you take the risk of destroying the transmit side of your receiver. Antenna efficiency may or may not take VSWR into account, it will be specifically stated in the datasheet if it is.

In order to calculate the overall efficiency of the radiating system, including the VSWR, when the antenna is fed by a 50 \$\Omega\$ source impedance, we relate the VSWR to the magnitude of the antenna's reflection coefficient \$|\Gamma|\$ (or equivalently Return Loss (dB) or \$|S_{11}|\$) by:

$$
|\Gamma| = \frac{\text{SWR} - 1}{\text{SWR} + 1}.
$$

The overall efficiency of the system including reflections from the antenna is then,

$$
\eta = \eta_{rad}(1-|\Gamma|^2),
$$
where \$\eta_{rad}\$ is the overall radiation efficiency of the antenna element.

Typically, acceptable SWR ratios are on the order of 2:1 or less, where a 2:1 VSWR corresponds to a reflection coefficient of approximately -10 dB.